# Retrieving value from localStorage and then setting and resetting variable (or potentially state) in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage, react-context

I have a small working portfolio site built using React that I want to use to feature both my graphic design and web development work. Visitors are greeted with a landing page featuring "project card" components that link to subsequent pages with information about each individual project. I would like visitors to be able to choose which types of projects to view, toggling between "Design" and "Web."

To accomplish this, `Header.js` features two `Link` elements with `onClick` attributes that save a "design" or "web" value (from functions held in context) to `localStorage`. I'm having trouble now retrieving those values to use as props so the `Landing.js` component can pass whichever value that was chosen to the project card components and render either my graphic design or web work. I would like to keep the header consistent across the entire site, so these `Link` elements are meant to simultaneously filter my projects and also route the visitor back to the main landing page. (`projectlists.js` features an array of project objects each with a "field" key and a corresponding value of either "design" or "web".

The functions in context update localStorage appropriately; I'm just not sure how to retrieve that value and use it as the prop I need. The correct projects appear when navigating to a sample project info page, for example, and then back to the main page, but I can't toggle between "Design" and "Web" from the main landing page itself at `"/"`.

Is the use of context overcomplicating things? Could this issue also stem from automatically placing "web" in localStorage upon first visit?

**Landing.js**

```
import React from "react";
import '../App.css';

import Header from "./Header";
import Projects from "./Projects";
import Contact from "./Contact";
import Footer from "./Footer";

import projects from "../utils/projectlists.js";

export default function Landing() {
  const newField = localStorage.getItem("field");

  if (!newField) {
    localStorage.setItem("field", "web")
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />

      <Projects projects={ 
        projects.filter(project => project.field === newField)
      } />

      <Contact />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Header.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { useSite } from "../utils/SiteContext";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import '../App.css';

function Header() {
  const { pickDesign, pickWeb } = useSite();

  return (
    <div>      
        <header>
          <ul>
            <li className="header-left"><Link to="/" onClick={pickDesign}>DESIGN</Link></li>
            <li className="header-left"><Link to="/" onClick={pickWeb}>WEB</Link></li>
          </ul>
          
        </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

**SiteContext.js**

```
import React, { createContext, useContext } from "react";

export const SiteContext = createContext();

export const useSite = () => useContext(SiteContext);

export default function SiteProvider({ children }) {

    const pickDesign = () => {
      if (localStorage.getItem("field") !== "design") {
        localStorage.setItem("field", "design");
      };
    };

    const pickWeb = () => {
      if (localStorage.getItem("field") !== "web") {
        localStorage.setItem("field", "web");
      };
    };
  
    return (
      <SiteContext.Provider value={{ pickDesign, pickWeb }}>
        {children}
      </SiteContext.Provider>
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a problem with your `landing` file.
You are storing your local storage data in a variable but your ui doesn't update because you dont change any state.

Change your `landing.js` to this:

```
const [newField, setNewField] =  useState("");

useEffect(() => { 
  const field = localStorage.getItem("field", "web");
  if(field) setNewField(field)
  else {
    localStorage.setItem("field", "web")
    setNewField("web")
  }
}, [])
```